PAST PASSIVE VOICE - Urgent Question That Confuses Me
I would sincerely appreciate your guidance with this particular question.
In the past passive voice, what is the difference in meaning between the following:
The window broke last night.
The window was broken last night.
In the passive voice we use be + past participle. The past participle is broken and not broke, hence my confusion. Is there a nuance I am missing?
I am confused in that I wonder if they mean the same thing. If not, then can you explain.
Thank you for your time!

"The window was broken last night" implies that an unnamed agent (person, object, or event) broke the window. "The window broke last night" doesn't address agency—it leaves open the possibility that the window broke itself or broke spontaneously without an assignable cause. On another level, "The window broke last night" specifies when the break occurred ("last night"), whereas "The window was broken last night" can be read as stating either that the break occurred last night or that someone observed the broken window last night (without claiming when the break may have occurred).

'The window broke' is talking about the window itself so when we hear this, we imagine the actual glass cracking across. 'The window was broken last night's speaks of the action taken to break the window - so then we imagine the assailant, the thief, actually breaking the window. With the first statement, we might look for sellotape. With the second one, we might call the police or start an investigation.
